# Why can't I use await keyword in my Windows Phone 7.1 MvvmCross project while using the Microsoft.Bcl - cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I am unable to use the await keyword in my MvvmCross Windows Phone 7.1 project while using the Microsoft.Bcl "Microsoft BCL Portability Pack".

I have posted the code for the sample project that I describe below on [GitHub and the await error occurs on this line](https://github.com/kstreet/PortableMvxAsync/blob/master/PortableMvxAsync.MvxUseThePlugin.Core/ViewModels/FirstViewModel.cs#L50).

When I try to build the third "Core" Windows Portable Class Library (PCL) that contains the FirstViewModel, I get the errors of:

```
Type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> not awaitable under VS red squiggles, and
Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' when building.
```

There are four projects in the solution:

1. A Windows Portable Class Library (PCL) with an interface in it that
   references that "Task" object provided by the BCL.
2. A Windows Phone Class Library targeting OS 7.1 that implements the
   interface above and also uses "Task" from the BCL.
3. Another Windows Portable Class Library (PCL) that provides the
   "Core" functionality of the app, including the ViewModel.
4. The Windows Phone 7.1/"7.5" application that tries to reference and
   consume the DLL's above.

The first two projects containing the interface and the implementation of the interface compile without any errors. But the 3rd "Core" PCL fails to build with the errors shown above.

**More Details If You Want Them:**

- I tried this App.config "fix" as described here in the "known BCL issues":
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx .But that did not resolve the error when I added App.config to just the "Core" project, nor when I tried to add the same App.config to every project.  It is possible that I am not using the right version in the  element or I just did the App.config stuff incorrectly.
- Every project in the solution that is set to target a PCL are set to "Profile104" in Visual Studio.

Those DLL's are located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile104\
```

- This PCL profile is shown as targeting these platforms in the Visual Studio project properties:
  .NET for Windows Store apps, .NET 4.5, Silverlight 4+, and Windows 7.5+
- Every project in the solution also has reference to the Microsoft.Bcl "Microsoft BCL Portability Pack" via NuGet.
- All four projects are using MvvmCross (Mvx).
- None of the projects in this sample are trying to target anything related to the Xamarin Droid/iOS stack yet.  It is all Windows and is still failing on the await keyword.
- The PCL with the interface in it and the Windows Phone Class Library both use the Mvx CrossCore NuGet Package and are setup to be consumed as "Mvx Plugins".
- The "Core" PCL is using the full MvvmCross NuGet package and contains the FirstViewModel where the await error is occurring.
- The Windows Phone App project references the full MvvmCross as well, with the Windows Phone-specific Mvx files pulled in to it.
- as mentioned, [see the failing sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/kstreet/PortableMvxAsync/blob/master/PortableMvxAsync.MvxUseThePlugin.Core/ViewModels/FirstViewModel.cs#L50).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package.

These packages were previously unavailable on non-Microsoft platforms, but as part of the Xamarin collaboration Microsoft [relicensed them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx) to be usable under all platforms.

Comment: I think all it takes is typing a book on SO, hitting submit, and then you realizing this :)  Thank you.  I added that NuGet to just the Core PCL and it built.  DUH! Wow, that was stupid! :)  Still not sure if the Mvx app is working yet but adding that NuGet for sure fixed await error, obviously :)  I am testing that the app will work and will accept this when it allows me to.

Comment: Just a note that Microsoft thankfully removed the "Windows Only" licensing restrictions from the BCL and other packages which makes this A LOT better for portable cross-platform development: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx

Comment: Microsoft.Bcl.Async is WP7.5+, not WP7.1+

Comment: @Cœur: WP 7.1 and WP 7.5 are the same platform. WP 7.5 is the marketing name; WP 7.1 is used internally.

Comment: So confusing... Why Visual Studio target is showing 7.1 and Nuget packages 7.5? I lost a day of support with clients asking me if we could support 7.1, and me answering "no, I only see 7.5 compatibility for async". Now, what is 7.8 is my next mystery...