# Should I be using Background Worker For this?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7

I am building a windows phone 7 application and I have a refresh button on my view. I also have a label saying when the view was last refreshed.

I want to update the label once every minute but not sure what to use? Should I use a regular thread or a background worker?

I never dabbled with threading too much yet in wp7.

Comment: Is it exactly WP7 or WP7.5? VS2010 or VS2012+?

Comment: Targeting 7.1 not sure what version of VS is relevant(I use both as I sometimes work on windows 7 which I need VS2010 and sometimes VS2012 as I am on windows 8)

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  Use a `Timer` to perform an operation periodically after an interval of time has passed.

Comment: Is that general where DispatcherTimer is more specific?

Comment: @chobo2 There are many different types of timers, each with various advantages and disadvantages.  Use whichever one you prefer. Some of the context-specific timers are worth using, some aren't.

Comment: Do you have a link to these different timers?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried that myself, but I think you should be able to use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) with WP7.1+ (based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370330/1768303)). However, you'd have to use VS2012+ for your project, VS2010 isn't suitable.

Then the code would be as simple as below, and will be executed on the main UI thread without hurting the UI responsiveness.

```
async Task UpdateUI(CancellationToken token)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        await TaskEx.Delay(1000, token); // pause for 1s
        this.Label.Text = "Updated: " + i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DispatcherTimer to call a DoStuff method every minute and update the label content with current time.

```
using System; 
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls; 
using System.Windows.Threading;  
namespace Clock 
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DispatcherTimer refreshTimer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();

            this.refreshTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(RefreshTimer_Tick);
            refreshTimer.Start();
        }

        private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }

        private void DoStuff()
        {
            //Do stuff
            lastUpdateLabel.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
}
```

All the calls are made in UIThread, so if you need to do long running stuff, you still need to create a background worker on DoStuff method.

Comment: cool, How about if your doing the dispatcher in a ViewModel and navigate back to another form. What would be the best way to stop t his timer?